# Cython error: Cannot convert Python object to type 'int *' error, when passing an Integer array to a function

Tags: python, pass-by-reference, cython

I am trying to pass an integer array to a function in Cython and I cannot understand why I get the error mentioned in the title.

A sample code of what I am trying to do is the following:

```
cpdef foo(int *table):
for i in range(10):
    table[i] = i

cdef int *temp=<int *>malloc(10*sizeof(int))
foo(temp)

for i in range(10):
    print temp[i]
```

I would appreciate any pointers as to how to pass the array correctly to the function. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue here is the function is `cpdef` - this means it can be called from both C and Python code, and means all arguments must be Python objects (otherwise how would one call it from Python?)

Declare it as `cdef` instead.